# ForegroundStyle visual effects not working in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a frosted glass background effect. I've seen many tutorials and the way to go seems to be using  something like `.foregroundStyle(.thickMaterial)` or `.background(.thickMaterial)`.

However, Xcode just does not recognise any of those. I get the error: `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'thickMaterial'`.

I don't think this is a problem with my code because I could start a completely new project and copy the example from the [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-visual-effect-blurs) website, but I still get that error.

What could be the issue?

I'm using Xcode version 12.4.

Comment: That extension is available since iOS 15, so you need Xcode 13+.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Asperi Oh! Easy fix then. Thank you

Comment: @sinio: If you want stay on Xcode 12.4, you can use UIKit Blur as well, no issue being in lower version.